# Having Problems with Collection in android

Tags: java, android, list, sharedpreferences

I am having some problems with implementation of Collection in android. The code is given below. I compare the position chosen in an alert dialog and accordingly call collection and its related function. But there seems to be problem and java.lang NullPointerException occurs all the time. i Call these Collection functions at the OnCreate method of the Applciation Start-Up Activity.

```
private void onStartPref() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // try {

    SharedPreferences pref2 = getApplication().getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int loadPosition = pref2.getInt("MyKey", isChecked);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position : " + loadPosition,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (pref2.contains("MyKey")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IF" + loadPosition,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (loadPosition == 0) {
            Collections.reverse(applist);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Reverses the present order list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else if (loadPosition == 1) {
            Collections.sort(applist,
                    new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(
                            packageManager));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorts Alphabetically",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (loadPosition == 2) {
            Collections.shuffle(applist);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Shuffles the present order selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO PREF" + loadPosition,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // } catch (Exception e) {
    // // TODO: handle exception
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR : " + e,
    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Log.i("ERROR", "" + e);
    // e.printStackTrace();
    // }

}
```

I am reversing , shuffling , sorting the order of my list but the application force closes. Can anybody help me with this Exception ? Can anybody also tell me how to load a list dynamically after these changes without reloading the activity or scrolling the list ?
Thanks

**LOG -----------------**

```
01-26 01:29:15.872: I/ERROR(26192): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 01:29:15.872: W/System.err(26192): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at java.util.Collections.reverse(Collections.java:1719)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at com.example.allapps.AllAppsActivity.onStartPref(AllAppsActivity.java:462)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at com.example.allpps.AllAppsActivity.onCreate(AllAppsActivity.java:252)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-26 01:29:15.882: W/System.err(26192): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

I use the methods in OnCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();

    new LoadApplications().execute();
    onStartPref();

}
```

---

LoadApplication is the main method regarding the applist. I use it in OnCreate Method and the method function is below.

```
private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager
                .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(AllAppsActivity.this,
                R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setListAdapter(listadaptor);
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(AllAppsActivity.this, null,
                "Loading Please Wait...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the nullpoexception? And where is `applist` initialized?

Comment: i Have updated the question hope this helps in answering the question

Comment: Created LoadApplication Method and Used LoadApplciation Method in OnCreate MEthod.

Comment: I would check the contents of appList, either by logging or debugging.  The documentation doesn't say null elements will cause an exception but it could be that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to initialize applist in  the doInBackground method of an AsyncTask. I.e. there is no guarantee that when you call onStartPref, it will be initialized.

I would suggest to call onStartPref in onPostExecute.